# condition to check if variable is defined (typescript)

Tags: typescript

What is the best way to check if the variable has a value or not, in typescript 4.2?
My variable could take a boolean value. I guess `if(v){}` won't work, since `false` could ignore the condition.

Comment: `v !== undefined`, maybe? It's hard to say without context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the variable can take a boolean value, so you need to check the type of your variable

```
if( typeof v === 'boolean'){ // enters code block if variable v is boolean and have a value }
```

or you can simply check if the type of a variable is not undefined

```
if( typeof v !== 'undefined'){ //enters code block if not undefined }
```

Comment: Using "typeof" is the best way to go. I prefer to use your second option. thank you for your help.